# How to refresh froala editor after submiting?

Tags: wysiwyg, froala

I use froala editor v2 in my projects. After form submiting I send data via ajax and I would like to refresh editor to initial state. I learned  [methods](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/methods) of froala and didn't find suitable one.I suppose I need to use combination of methods.Could anybody help with it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my "dirty" work around:

```
$('.fr-element.fr-view').html("");
```

Emptying the content by setting the html inside of the froala element to `""`
(if your froala generated element also uses `.fr-element .fr-view` as classes).